# Yarn workspaces run shell command for each

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'd like to use Yarn's Workspaces feature to run a shell command in each of my workspaces.

Yarn supports the `yarn workspaces run foo` command, but `foo` must be a script defined in `package.json`, not an arbitrary command (eg. `echo "foobar"`).

Ideally I'd like to have a single script eg. `"foo": "yarn workspaces run echo 'foobar'"` in my top level `package.json`. One workaround is to add a script called `foobar` to each workspace's `package.json`, and have the top-level `package.json` delegate to these, but with a non-trivial number of workspaces this becomes cumbersome to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

In Yarn 3 (Berry) [`exec`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/exec) and [`workspaces foreach`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/workspaces/foreach) commands can be utilised to achieve this. For example: `yarn workspaces foreach exec echo 'foobar'`